# Как определить включен AdBlock или нет?

Tags: javascript

Как можно определить javascript-ом включен AdBlock или нет? Просто есть слайдер и когда включен AdBlock, то вместо него пустое место. Баннеры показывают оригинальный размер 1x1 px.

Comment: а почему не переписать слайдер? Или слайдер показывает рекламу и поэтому был забанен:)?

Comment: Надёжно никак. Adblock загружен до вас, и может в принципе переписать ваш HTML как ему вздумается.

Кроме того, я считаю задачу борьбы с отключением рекламы юзером глубоко неэтичной: клиент вправе обходить навязываемый ему раздражающий контент.

Если ваш контент не рекламный, обратитесь к мейнтейнерам списков блокировки насчёт ложного срабатывания.

Comment: Слайдер просто показывает баннера, которые относятся к акциям.
Конечно согласен про раздражающий контект, если это реклама, но когда это просто баннера, которые сообщают о акциях на сайте, то я здесь ничего такого не вижу.

Comment: @TF03: А он имеет имя «баннер»? Не удивительно, что его блокируют. Слово «баннер» прочно ассоциируется с рекламой. Переименуйте.

Comment: Значит, ищите отличия. Но всё равно, вырезать можно что угодно, и постоянно с этим биться бессмысленно. Максимум - изучить актуальные дефолтные списки блокировки (типа EasyList) и стараться под них не попадать.

Comment: @VladD: Да, баннера лежат в папке banner и в названии есть слово banner.

Comment: @TF03: ну так переименуйте.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо конечно, но вопрос стоял по другому =)

Comment: @TF03, как сейчас стоит вопрос - он вообще смысла не имеет. Ну определите вы что включен адблок, дальше что?
Выкините какое-нибудь идиотское сообщение уровня "у вас включён адблок, выключите его чтобы работать с нашим сайтом"?

-----

А у меня вообще адблока нет, ваш URL баннерный в сквиде прописан (это к вопросу об "определении адблока" в ответах ниже). И что, какая вам польза от этой информации, а посетителю сайта - какое удобство?

Comment: У меня адблок блочит только баннеры, где явно указано слово banner, adv и так далее, так что просто переименовывайте, как народ советует и будет вам счастье. Если баннеры грузяться от партнеров, то лучше их сохранять у себя, а затем выводить на сайте. Если они периодически меняются, то подгружайте их скриптом пару раз в день, неделю, месяц и тд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня так получилось:

```js
  var o = document.getElementById('ad-detect');
  var ad_visible = o && (o.style.display != 'none') && (o.width * o.height);
```

```html
<img id="ad-detect" class="ads banner" src="/ads/banner.gif" alt="This must be hidden" />
```

banner.gif можно 1х1 прозрачный/белый...

Задача была - порекомендовать посетителю блокировщик рекламы, если его ещё почему-то нет :p

Answer (score 5):

Есть такая фишка:

```
<img class="ad-detect" src="/img/ad.gif" />

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           var $adDetect = $('.ad-detect:visible').length;
           if ($adDetect) {
               console.log('adblock on');
           }
      });
</script>

"/img/ad.gif" - должна быть любая картинка
```

Answer (score 2):

я как-то столкнулся с проблемой  html и http

1. Убрать из верстки слайдера имена классов и айди которые напоминают рекламу. `ad-banner`, `banner`,  и т.д
2. Мои картинки находились в папке `/banners`  и адблок прерывал их загрузку. Переименуйте директорию

Answer (score 0):

Видел один сайт, который с помощью js определяет включен ли adblock, и если включен то выводит блок о том чтобы отключили. Не знаю что за сайт, но в js у него была ссылка на [этот скрипт](http://pjatnuchanu.ucoz.ua/adblock.txt)

Comment: Вот это скрипт, какой-то стремный... Я находил на одном сайте скрипт - они проверяли высоту и ширину блока, где реклама, но для слайдера такое не сработает(

Comment: так вам нужно определить включен ли адблок. или блочит ли адблок ваш слайдер ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/p1zNmC3q так-то всё просто.

Comment: Как-то выше пример намного проще =)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующую библиотеку: https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock

[Demo](https://fuckadblock.sitexw.fr/)

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий. Чтобы его не снесли админы, а Вы получили балы в карму, есть смысл дополнить Ваш ответ подробностями об использовании библиотеки. Ссылки на чужой ресурс в данном случае недостаточно, она может измениться.