# Защита от скачивания файлов, если включен AdBlock

Tags: javascript, css, защита

Как реализовать подобную защиту от скачивания файлов на своем сайте (**только для кнопки загрузки**, остальное пусть пользователь читает стр. хоть с adblock, хоть без), если у пользователя включен AdBlock?
Нужно чтобы пользователь для загрузки отключал обязательно свой adblock в браузере.

---

не картинку, подразумевается защита кнопки (download) с ссылкой на объект (svg, zip, exe и др.)

Comment: никак, если ты загружаешь картинку - ее можно скачать.

Comment: Ответ состоит из 2х пунтков:
1. [Определить, включен ли adblock](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/333930/Как-определить-включен-adblock-или-нет?rq=1)
2. Если включен, не загружать файлы. Т.е. загрузка (html-контент) должен быть динамическим. Хотя почти на любую меру (ограничение) найдется контрмера.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать вот такую штуковину, и при наличии адблока у пользователя вашего сайта применять необходимые стили к вашей кнопки для загрузки или полностью ее скрывать.

```js
var adBlockEnabled = false;
var testAd = document.createElement('div');
var download = document.getElementsByClassName('download');
testAd.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
testAd.className = 'adsbox';
document.body.appendChild(testAd);
window.setTimeout(function() {
  if (testAd.offsetHeight === 0) {
    adBlockEnabled = true;
    document.querySelector('.download').classList.add("download__deactive");
    document.querySelector('.download__2').classList.add("download__deactive__2");
  }
  testAd.remove();
  console.log('AdBlock Enabled? ', adBlockEnabled)
}, 1200);
```

```css
.download__deactive {
  background-color: red;
}
.download__deactive__2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="down">Просто кнопка</button>
<button class="download">Скачать</button>
<button class="download__2">Скачать</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключите скрипт

```
<head>
    <script src="js/showads.js"></script>
</head>
```

внутри него пропишите

```
var ads = true;
```

На кнопку навесьте запуск функции по клику, а в функции:

```
if(ads==true)
  {
  //код для загрузки файла
  }
else
  {
  alert('adblock включен!');
  }
```